# How can I run scripts from package.json in windows with linux commnads?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to start the server on my local system with scripts in my package.json. It seems it has relative paths and commands like cp.

I have installed cygwin. I also tried to manually change those commands to windows commands. I used \ instead of / in paths.

```
"prestart": "cp -v ./src/index.html ./dist && node svg-processing.js && cp -v ./src/components/icons.css ./dist",
```

Comment: slashes work in both directions on windows. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can use linux commands directly with [wsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/wsl/about) in windows.